# data that goes into the database generates C:\xampp\tmp\phpACA2.tmp in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have some inputs in it including thumbnails and images, i have some validation conditions to check both data from those inputs. The data entered in the images column is entered successfully but in the thumbnail column it produces C:\xampp\tmp\phpACA2.tmp, how do you make validation so that the data enters properly?

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

  
        if($request->file('thumbnail')){
            $request->file('thumbnail')->store('post-images');
        };
        
        $image = array();
        if ($files = $request->file('images')) {
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $image_name = md5(rand(1000, 10000));
                $ext = strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension());
                $image_full_name = $image_name.'.'.$ext;
                $upload_path = 'public/storage/post-images/';
                $image_url = $upload_path.$image_full_name;
                $file->move($upload_path, $image_full_name);
                $image[] = $image_url;
            }
        }

        Product::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'subtitle' => $request->subtitle,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'features' => $request->features,
            'categories_id' => $request->categories_id,
            'thumbnail' => $request->thumbnail,
            'file' => $request->file,
            'images' => implode('|', $image),

        ]);
        return redirect('/dashboard/products');

    }
```

column thumbnail that enter into the database

[thumbnail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylRBs.png)

column images that enter into the database
[images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iole.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should not assign `thumbnail` as `$request->thumbnail` (this will get its local path). You will need to assign it like:

(by taking into account that `'post-images'` drive's path is `public/storage/post-images/`)

```
'thumbnail' => 'public/storage/post-images/'.$request->file('thumbnail')->getClientOriginalName()
```

My recommendation is to apply same logic that you did for each `image` to thumbnail as well.

1. Generate unique name
2. Store it with generated name and its extension
3. Then save its path and name in database